# error while running the WCF application

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Hello all when i am trying to run the application i am getting error like this one..
[image]

The service.svc file has the following code..

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="prodcuts.ProductServiceImpl" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/ProductsService.cs" %>
```

Please help me..
Thankyou

Comment: Can you post your service Implementation class as well?

Comment: As Wolfwyrd points out - is there actually a typo in your `Service` declaration? should it read: "prod*uc*ts" instead of "prod*cu*ts"?

Answer (score 2):

WCF is trying to load a type from your application that doesnt exist. On first look it looks like a typo - did you mean to use the name "Products" rather than "prodcuts"?

Comment: @Wolf..i wrote "products" only, not "Products"